# Memory leak when searching multiple log file patterns with Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am writing a script that searches for a specific pattern in multiple log files with Powell Shell. There is a serious memory leak when executing the script, so I am wondering how to search the files one by one. Help.

```
$LOG_FILE = 'C:\test\test\test_*.log
$FIND_LINE = Get-Content $LOG_FILE | findstr 'test'
```

Comment: did you try to use Select-String instead of findstr.exe?

Comment: If you want to save memory, I recoment to use the [PowerShell pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines) as it is intended, don't assign it to a variable but stream it from the start to the end: `Get-Content $LOG_FILE |Select-String 'test' |Set-Content $out_file`

Comment: @iRon, if the input comes from a file, `Select-String -Path $LOG_FILE 'test'` is much faster and more memory-efficient.

Comment: Even if I use select-string, it grabs the resource in the same way. I guess it's because I'm searching multiple files at once. Is there a way to search multiple files sequentially?

Answer (score 1):

[`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) is slow and memory-hungry, so it's best to let [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) - PowerShell's more fully-featured analog to `findstr.exe` - search the files of interest directly:

```
$linesFound = (Select-String -Path C:\test\test\test_*.log -Pattern 'test').Line
```

Note:

- By default, the `-Pattern` argument is interpreted as a [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions); add the `-SimpleMatch` switch to perform a *verbatim* substring search.
- `Select-String`, like PowerShell in general, is case-*insensitive* by default;
  add `-CaseSensitive` if needed.
- `Select-String` wraps the lines it finds in [`[Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo) instances that contain metadata about each match; accessing the `.Line` property returns the matching line.

  - In [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) you can use the `-Raw` switch to directly request the matching lines only.

Answer (score 0):

Get the log files into an array and then loop through them. Don't use findstr as that is not native powershell its an old cmd executable. Use Select-String as others have said.

```
[array]$LOG_FILE = Get-ChildItem C:\test\test\test_*.log
[string[]]$FIND_LINE = ForEach ($L in $LOG_FILE) { Get-Content $L | Select-String 'test' }
```

Then you could export the results to a text file like so:

```
$FIND_LINE | Out-File "C:\test\FoundLines.txt"
```

Since you mentioned memory leaks and such. Powershell can eat memory it never returns within a given session but if you save this into a script and execute it as a script then it should clear up memory after the script ends.  However there are a few tricks to clean up memory within loops like this dotnet command for garbage collection:

```
[system.gc]::Collect()
```

It will add a tiny bit of processing time to each iteration of the loop though so I would test how long it takes with and without the garbage collection to make sure it's worth it.  I suggest also reading about some other methods and caveats with that mentioned here:
http://www.jhouseconsulting.com/2017/09/25/addressing-the-powershell-garbage-collection-bug-1825

And also use PowerShell 7 (if you can install it) as it would likely be faster and more efficient.